# fitting non-normal multivariate distributions in R

Tags: r, distributions, density-function, fitting, quantiles

I have many (*n=317,823*) observations on two variables. I want to fit a bivariate distribution to my observations, in order to identify descriptive features of the distribution (quantiles). However, my data do not appear normal or log-normal and I haven't found a package on the relevant CRAN [task view](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Distributions.html) that can help me. I am hoping to learn:

- if there is an existing workflow to fit a somewhat idiosyncratic pdf like the one below
- whether I am 'asking the wrong question' given my weak math skills. Maybe there is an easier way to approach my problem.

**Context**: my data originate from satellite observations of forest harvest around the world. For a randomly selected subset of these observations (1 pixel/100km2) I have sampled two global raster layers, one showing forest canopy height and one showing time to access cities. I believe that these are two observable aspects (height, accessibility) of a multidimensional distribution of 'forest quality', which contains many other unbelievable aspects (e.g., species composition). I am trying to characterize the joint distribution so that I may categorize subsequent observations of forest harvest as falling within particular (joint) quantiles.

**Sampling data** plotted in base via `table()` and `persp()`:
[image]

Data are strictly positive by construction...and that's a funny looking (asymmetrical) pdf. Clearly the long tail is important. I used the excellent r package `{fitdistrplus}` to look at each variable separately, following the vignette.

Some diagnostic results for dimension 'height':
[image]

...and for dimension 'accessibility to cities':
[image]

The first looks like it could be described by a log-normal or gamma, and the second by gamma...possible a bivariate gamma distribution could fit the joint density well?

**Current approach** (my best option) is to accept the (large) inaccuracy and model the joint distribution as log-normal, e.g. by taking logs of both variables and fitting with package `fMultivar`, and then attempting to work out isolines as described [in this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/64680/how-to-determine-quantiles-isolines-of-a-multivariate-normal-distribution).

[here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1V1Hu-CA3_8SilRrXfYjrvHHxv28KOjN1?usp=sharing) are two downsampled versions of the dataset, obtained as `data[sample(nrow(data),round(nrow(data)/scale)),]`, with scale=10 ("medium") or 100 ("small")

Comment: [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/64194/fitting-distributions-in-r) is a related-but-not-useful post in which OP was told to take a different approach

Comment: There's the [mixsmsn](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mixsmsn/index.html) package for fitting skew normal, Student $t$, skew $t$ etc. distributions. Might be worth a try.

Comment: My approach would be to re-sample down to a 50x50 grid (2500 total data points) and perform an equation search, then fit all of the data to that equation. I would down-sample as an equation search with 300,000 data points would be too much for the equipment I personally have available, and a 50x50 re-sample grid visually looks like it would be quite sufficient for a good equation search based on your plots.

Comment: @corey979, those distributions are defined over negative values: my values (height, travel time) are strictly positive (0s were dropped as bad data). I've dialed down the bin width on the accessibility histogram to show that distribution better. I don't think the smallest bin is important (can explain) so that pretty much looks like decreasing exponential to me.

Comment: @JamesPhillips but what equations (== distributions?) would you use? I can post downsampled data.

Comment: My open source curve and surface fitting web site, zunzun.com, has hundreds of known, named equations and a "function finder" to perform equation searches using them. Post a link to the downsampled data and I will see if it might suggest any candidate surface equations of the form "z = f(x,y)". It's worth a try to see what turns up.

Comment: [posts about bivariate gamma](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=bivar*+gamma+answers%3A1).  You could also try copulas, [tag:copula]. The R package `VGAM` do have a bivariate gamma implementation. Can you post a link to the data?

Comment: Thanks for these replies! Downsampled data has been added. @JamesPhillips, neat site! just a reminder that my problem treats the joint distribution as a PDF (I am interested in analyzing percentiles/quantiles, e.g., "rare" and "common" intervals).

Comment: Do you mean that a fitted surface equation of the form "z=f(x,y)" would not be of any use to you?

Comment: I'm not sure. In this question I ask about fitting a bivariate Probability Density Function. This reflects a "theoretical" position (I'm sampling from an underlying distribution of which I can observe only two dimensions) and a "practical" concern (I want to talk about how rare or common observations are, <=> how probable they are). "z=f(x,y)" can describe the surface of a PDF only...I suppose one could integrate over a surface equation and call that a PDF? But this is beyond me, & I am hoping to stick to well-trod ground.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. My now-understood-to-be-incorrect approach will not work for you here, my apology.

Comment: Not at all; thank you for your attention/suggestions. @kjetilbhalvorsen, 'VGAM::bigamma.mckay' apparently requires Pr(X<Y)=1 (as I guess [you know](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/22729/mckays-bivariate-gamma-distribution)). This is not the case in ~5% of my data...and the generation procedure referenced in that link ('X is sum of  a subset of squares of Y') doesn't make sense with my data...also wouldn't the X<Y condition be kind of nonsensical when X and Y are measured in different units? (as here). Will post bigamma.mckay fits if I can wrangle nice plots & will try cupolas next.